# In George Orwell's Burmese Days, what word is the censored "b--s" supposed to be?

Tags: george-orwell, censorship, burmese-days

Here's a passage where Westfield talks about possibly having to allow Natives into the European club:

> "Got to put up with it, I suppose", he said. "B--s of natives are getting into all the Clubs nowadays. Even the Pegu Club, I'm told. Way this country's going, you know. We're about the last Club in Burma to hold out against 'em"

I can't figure out what the "B--s" is supposed to be. Could it be bollocks? I haven't heard that word being used in this way yet, and it seems weird to me to censor bollocks but not the n-word, although I guess those were different times.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but could it be bastards?

Comment: @user14111 That may definitely be it, thanks!

Comment: Bastards, buggers, blighters, ... half the swearwords in the English language begin with B.

Comment: Do any of those suggestions work in context, though? The censored word has to mean "lots".

Comment: @Gareth Rees That's also what I've wondered. It feels like it should be "lots", but it could be "bastards" or any of the other suggestions. It's just a bit weirdly phrased in that case, I think, but I'm not a native speaker, so I might be wrong.

Comment: How Orwellian of the editors!

Comment: “Buttloads”.  None of the other suggestions mean “lots”

Comment: @verbose: It's a good idea but *OED* has no citations before 1988, which suggests that it would be anachronistic for *Burmese Days* (published 1934, set in the 1920s).

Comment: @GarethRees “The great tragedy of science—the slaying of a beautiful hypothesis by an ugly fact” (Thomas Huxley)

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Blighter isn't the sort of word that you need to censor, nor is bounder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost certainly "***[buggers](https://www.lexico.com/definition/bugger)***". Several other possible options ("***bastards***", ***"balls"***) are used later in the book without bowdlerisation.

> 'Now, you damned swab, will you take that back?' 'No, I will not.'
>   'You oily swine! You nigger's Nancy Boy! **You crawling,
>
>   sneaking, f - -  bloody bastard!'**
>   'Order!' exclaimed Mr Macgregor.

and

> 'Here, Macgregor, we've read this notice, and we all think
>   this idea of electing a native to the Club is absolute...' **Ellis
>   was going to have said 'absolute balls',** but he remembered Mrs Lackersteen's presence and checked himself.

---

The context in which it's used later in the book fits 'buggers' well and doesn't fit the final option (***"bollocks"***) at all well.

> to be governing a set of damn black swine who've been slaves since the beginning of history, and instead of ruling them in the only way they understand, we go and treat them as equals. And **all you silly b - - s take it for granted**.

and

> that's against all the Government regulations. Ellis was a little
>   vexed about it. **"Why didn't you plug some of the b - - s when
>   you had the chance?"** he said.